# Spearman correlation in the presence of many ties - how to spot a problem?

Tags: r, correlation, monte-carlo, spearman-rho

I'm testing the hypothesis that there's a monotonic relationship between two variables. I think I should use a Spearman rank correlation test, since my data don't necessarily meet normality assumptions & have many outliers. However, there are many ties in the independent variable. How can I tell whether the ties are causing me a problem?

The data look something like this (R code):

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rep(1:10, 10)
y <- x + rnorm(length(x), sd=rep(x, 10))
```

[image]

One approach I can think of is to add a small random number to each x value many time, and look at the mean/median p-value, like so:

```
nReps <- 100
pVec <- rep(NA, 100)
for(i in 1:nReps) {
  xDodge <- x + rnorm(n=nReps, mean=0, sd=0.0001)
  pVec[i] <- cor.test(xDodge, y, method="spearman")$p.value
}
mean(pVec)
sd(pVec)
```

Does that method seem reasonable? Is there a previously-described method to assess the effect of ties on Spearman's rho, or a similar correlation method that does better with large numbers of ties?

Comment: How does any such correlation test for monotonicity - unless it  it's 1 (or -1), the relationship between sample quantities isn't monotonic. How does a p-value relating to to the usual Spearman test identify an underlying monotonic relationship as opposed to something else (perhaps one that is mostly increasing but isn't monotonic)?

Comment: Sloppy language - I should have just said that I would like to test  for a relationship between the variables without making assumptions as to the functional form of the relationship.

Comment: Oh, okay - if you're trying to identify a relationship with a test that has good power against underlying monotonic relationships, then no problem with wanting to use Spearman. I may come back on the ties issue if I get time today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use a permutation test.**  You only need to permute one of the variables independently of the other; here, the response is permuted.  Because the relationship in the example is strong, only a small number of permutations are needed (1000 in the example below).

As always, the actual statistic is compared to the distribution of permuted statistics.  The p-value is the estimate of the tail probability of the permutation distribution relative to the actual statistic.  In some cases the test statistic has a discrete distribution, so it's wise to check the frequencies with which (a) the permutation statistics *strictly* exceed the actual statistic and (b) the permutation statistics *equal or exceed* the actual statistic.  The code illustrates this by splitting the difference.

```
test <- function(y) suppressWarnings(cor.test(x, y, method="spearman")$estimate)
rho <- test(y)                                     # Test statistic
p <- replicate(10^3, test(sample(y, length(y))))   # Simulated permutation distribution

p.out <- sum(abs(p) > rho)    # Count of strict (absolute) exceedances
p.at <- sum(abs(p) == rho)    # Count of equalities, if any
(p.out + p.at /2) / length(p) # Proportion of exceedances: the p-value.
```

`suppressWarnings` quiets any complaints from `cor.test` that it cannot compute a p-value due to ties.

Comment: Package `coin` provides the function `spearman_test()` which implements a permutation test for Spearman's $\rho$. It also provides additional information about the permutation distribution, see `?support`.